# Alt or title attribute for Cross-browser HTML tooltip?

Tags: html

I'm looking for a cross browser solution to display information when "hovering" on an element, I know this can be done with JS dynamically but I'd prefer in this specific case a basic static HTML solution.

According to mozilla developers website ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Defining_Cross-Browser_Tooltips)) using title instead of alt is the best practice but I'd like more "field experience" to help me decide if I should go for `ALT`, `TITLE` attr or JavaScript

Thank you very much

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Title` attribute is for tooltips and is supported by all major browser. You should use it.

`Alt` attribute isn't about tooltips at all.